# How to do load test for Registration in JMETER

Tags: authentication, jmeter, registration, multiple-users

Iam very new to JMETER, how to test registration for multiple users & login. Is it possible using CSV file or any other method for multiple users ??

Can anyone please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If you have a file with username/password combinations - the most commonly used approach is reading the file with [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
2. Alternatives are:

   - [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) - if the credentials are in the database
   - [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) - the credentials are in Redis
   - etc.
3. If you're testing registration and "run and forget" approach is good for you - you can generate random usernames and passwords using suitable [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString), [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random), [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Random CSV DataSet Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) plugin in addition to the solutions given by Dmitri.

I have demonstrated use of [CSV DataSet Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element and [Random CSV DataSet Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) in [this video](https://youtu.be/1j6UIBU-J18).